# Looking for faster way to loop through dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

Thanks for reading my question, I have written some code on looping through each row of dataframe A (millions of rows) while look for any matching data in dataframe B and do some caluclations and append to dataframe A, I am quite sure I am not doing it in a right way and may I please ask are there any way I could speed up the process as it took age (in hours), thanks!

```
current_lot=0
average_price=0

for i in tqdm(range(len(df_price.values))):
 

    if len(df_trade[df_trade.index==df_price.iloc[i, 7]])>0:
       
      df_trade_sort = df_trade[df_trade.index==df_price.iloc[i, 7]]
      
      #Loop through sorted trade per minute
      for z in range(len(df_trade_sort.values)):

        #Calculate average price & current lot
        if df_trade_sort.iloc[z,1] == 'buy':
          if round(current_lot + df_trade_sort.iloc[z,3],2) != 0:
            average_price = (df_trade_sort.iloc[z,4]*df_trade_sort.iloc[z,3]+average_price*current_lot)/round(current_lot + df_trade_sort.iloc[z,3],2)
          else:
            average_price = 0
          current_lot = round(current_lot + df_trade_sort.iloc[z,3],2)

        else:
          if round(current_lot - df_trade_sort.iloc[z,3],2) != 0:
            average_price = (df_trade_sort.iloc[z,4]*-df_trade_sort.iloc[z,3]+average_price*current_lot)/round(current_lot - df_trade_sort.iloc[z,3],2)
          else:
            average_price = 0
          current_lot = round(current_lot - df_trade_sort.iloc[z,3],2)

    df_price.iloc[i,8]=current_lot
    df_price.iloc[i,9]=round(average_price,5)
    DD = 100000*abs(current_lot)*-abs(average_price-df_price.iloc[i,4])
    df_price.iloc[i,10] = round(DD,2)
```

Apologize for the unclear information, what I am trying to achieve is from df_price, I iterate over each minute and check in the df_trade table that do I have any trade for that particular minute, which then I will do the calculations with the trades and then appended the result back into the df_price dataframe under the "DD" column.

The input data is:

```
df_price:
Date    Time    Open    High    Low Close   Tick volume Datetime    Current_Lot Average_Price   DD
0   2017.01.02  00:41:00    1.70815 1.71041 1.70815 1.71041 4   2017-01-02 00:41:00 0   0   0
1   2017.01.02  00:42:00    1.70994 1.70994 1.70994 1.70994 1   2017-01-02 00:42:00 0   0   0
2   2017.01.02  00:43:00    1.70906 1.70968 1.70906 1.70968 5   2017-01-02 00:43:00 0   0   0
3   2017.01.02  00:44:00    1.70965 1.70965 1.70965 1.70965 1   2017-01-02 00:44:00 0   0   0

df_trade:
Time    #   Type    Order   Size    Price
2017-12-29 17:57:00 2468    buy 1234    0.01    1.73291
2017-12-29 17:55:00 2467    sell    1234    0.01    1.73291
2017-12-29 12:00:00 2466    buy 1233    0.01    1.72937
2017-12-29 10:33:00 2460    sell    1233    0.01    1.72937
2017-12-29 10:33:00 2461    sell    1222    0.02    1.73809
2017-12-29 10:33:00 2462    sell    1223    0.02    1.73457
```

Comment: The fastest way in pandas is **not to loop** and **never to use `iterrows`**, you should provide a minimal example of data and clearly explain what you try to achieve. There might be a way to vectorize.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt respond, i have include some sample data in the post

Comment: Could you provide the input as well as the output of what you are trying to achieve? As far as I understand `df_price` and `df_trade`  is your input, but what would the output be?

Comment: @ttsak the output will be the same df_price dataframe with the colcumn calculated after looping through the dataframe

Comment: @mozway, i have update the post with the input data sample, may i please have your view on any potentioal correction on my code, thanks in advance!!

Comment: @KLo do you mind specifying, based on `df_price`, `df_trade`, and their respective columns, what are you trying to achieve? Specifically the conditions you are looking to match.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres Thanks for helping, what i am trying to achieve was i am iterating through each minutes under the "datetime" column in the df_price dataframe and check matching under the "time" column in the df_trade dataframe that do i have any trade for that perticular minute, which if there is, i will then extract the trade parameters (lot number in that row in that specific minute) from the df_trade dataframe, do the calculations and then appended the number result back into the df_price dataframe under the "DD" column. But it just run super long with only little of my data

Comment: @KLo Which calculations do you want to do after extracting the parameters?

Comment: @GonçaloPeres the flow will be:
1. loop through df_price "datetime" column which is every minute
2. check if df_trade "time" column to see are there any trade in that particular minute
3. if there is one or more trade i.e. one or more row in df_trade with that specific minute, i will then record the "Size" and "price" of all these rows.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres
4. By having the "Size" and "price"  data, i will then calculate the "average_price" and "current_lot" value and then append back to the "Current_Lot" "Average_Price" and "DD" of that specific minutes/specific row in the df_price dataframe and then continue looping through the next row of the df_price dataframe